# Mac OS Mountain Lion - Apache running but localhost not working

Tags: macos, apache, unix, localhost, osx-mountain-lion

I loaded Apache Web server on Mac OS Mountain Lion with the command

```
sudo apachectl start
```

However, when I try to open localhost in Firefox, I get the message

> Not Found: The requested URL / was not found on this server. Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 Server at localhost Port 80

I edited both httpd.conf and httpd.conf.default to change

```
#ServerName www.website.com
```

to

```
ServerName localhost
```

It still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Found any solutions yet?

Comment: I am programming a web site in html and css and using server side includes to enable a consistent design and to avoid having to unnecessarily repeat code. Is that off topic? If not, I need to have my computer handling the server side includes so I can test my code. In that sense, apache is a tool, that enables me to test my code without having to upload to my web host, so getting apache up and running under mountain lion is essential to me. I would assume that there would be other web programmers who have experienced the same and could contribute to a solution.

Comment: I had the similar issue. The restart command didn't give any error or output which left me wondering what happened. Checking the ports, I found that apache wasn't running. Running this command `/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND` actually helped me see the actual error message and start apache successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check the permissions on the folder specified as the "DocumentRoot" in your "httpd.conf", and allow at least read access for the Apache user (which should by "_www" by default).
Otherwise you could do a "sudo chmod 755" on the "DocumentRoot" folder.
By the way, you should only modify the "httpd.conf" file, since the "httpd.conf.default" is a default configuration that you can use if you want to restore the Apache original configuration, by simply overwriting the "httpd.conf" file with the "httpd.conf.default" file.
I suppose that you've not enabled name-based virtual hosts, since when you enable name-based virtual hosts, the document root in the main config is ignored; instead, the root for the matching hostname will be used, and if none match it will default to the first virtual host.
Finally, when you have problems, the first thing to check is always the Apache error log file.
The location of the the error log can be found by looking at the "ErrorLog" directive in the Apache configuration file.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the following:

Comment: Sorry, pressed the return key accidentally the last time. This is what I was typing: Thanks. I did the following: (1) set permissions on DocumentRoot correctly, (2) Reverted changes to httpd.conf.default, (3) checked the error log and found this: "[client ::1] File does not exist: /usr/htdocs"

Comment: @Spartanblogger The error "File does not exist: /usr/htdocs" means that you have an error in your Apache configuration file. Where did you set "/usr/htdocs" in your "httpd.conf"?

Comment: Any success? I am stuck at the same point. Have tried everything but could not get the Forbidden error subside

Comment: @Raj Which error do you get in the error log?

Comment: My username.conf file has this:
<Directory "/Users/Raj/Projects/JoomlaWorkstation/">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

I have changed by document root to point to my Joomla sources. As you have asked I have looked into the error log and it tells the following:
[Sun Sep 30 23:22:46 2012] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Users/Raj/Sites/phpinfo.php

I have placed the php file for testing purpose. Though I have changed the document directory, it is still trying to point to my "Sites" directory

Answer (score 6):

To verify that a process is listening on port 80, you can use lsof in a terminal window:

```
$ sudo lsof -iTCP:80 -sTCP:LISTEN
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd      88 root    4u  IPv6 0xffffff8018804600      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd      90 _www    4u  IPv6 0xffffff8018804600      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   14843 _www    4u  IPv6 0xffffff8018804600      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

This will verify that you successfully enabled apache.

(I have xcode installed, but I think lsof is part of the normal install)

ADDED:

That confirms that apache is listening on port 80. The next step I would take is to look at the access logs, to see what apache logged when you requested '/' as shown in the error apache returned to your browser. This is what mine shows. Note that the http GET request is shown with the return code 200 (success):

```
bash-3.2# grep 'GET / ' /private/var/log/apache2/access_log 
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2012:16:46:45 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 44
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2012:16:49:44 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 44
```

You can also confirm what url your browser is requesting by refreshing your browser window, then confirming that apache logs that new request to the access_log.

Comment: I tried that and I got pretty much the same result (device ID was slightly different, obviously), EXCEPT that the PIDs were: 19275, 19277, and 19285.

Comment: Ok, so that confirms apache is running and listening, though in retrospect, that was clear from the apache error returned to your browser in the original question.

Comment: This is a very nice thorough answer. Keep it up!

Comment: You say "That confirms that apache is listening on port 80" ... what confirms this? What does unsuccessful output look like?

Comment: @jeff: The command `sudo lsof -iTCP:80 -sTCP:LISTEN` lists all processes that are listening on port 80, and in my example you can see that an instance of httpd is listening. If it were not, you should see no output from that command. You can see what it would look like by replacing `80` with any unused port number. (Try it with something like 88888)

Answer (score 1):

Comment out all of the `IfDefine !WEBSERVICE_ON` tags, keeping the content within -- there is no `WEBSERVICE` on Mountain Lion.